# Column value not getting updated based on pattern search of another column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R which has two columns Machine Name (character) and Region (factor). They have values as follows (few examples):

```
Machine.Name     Region 
1233.corp.pdo.om APAC 
xyz.om           Europe 
345.corp.pdo.cm  Europe 
abc12.cm         Americas
```

So I want to update the region with pdo for the machines which have corp.pdo in them. But when I am trying to update its not happening using if else.

I have tried using the below code,it doesn't throw error but doesn't update the value as desired:

```
df3_machine_region %>%mutate(Region= if_else(str_detect(Machine.Name, "corp.pdo"), "corp.pdo", as.character(Region)))
```

The output is still the same as above.

```
Machine.Name     Region 
1233.corp.pdo.om pdo 
xyz.om           Europe 
345.corp.pdo.cm  pdo 
abc12.cm         Americas
```

I have tried to do some troubleshooting but no success so far.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sure.I wl take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt actually works, the only thing missing is assigning the data back to original dataframe.

```
df3_machine_region <- df3_machine_region %>%
                     mutate(Region= if_else(str_detect(Machine.Name, "corp.pdo"), 
                      "corp.pdo", as.character(Region)))
```

However, it works here because of co-incidence not because the logic is correct. You are using regex here and `"."` has a special meaning in regex which needs to be escaped (`\\`) or use `fixed = TRUE`. Try this :

```
df3_machine_region$Region[grep("corp.pdo", df3_machine_region$Machine.Name, fixed = TRUE)] <- 'corp.pdo'
```

Comment: Hi Ronak.It worked.Thanks.Yes "." wasn't getting escaped.